# adding on load in body in masterpage

Tags: master-page

simple question, I am editing a masterpage and have inserted a js file that has a function that needs to be invoked with `body onload`. How would I be able to do this in the masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SharePoint specific

SharePoint provides the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` array. When the body is loaded, the onload event handler executes each function whose name is contained in this array, for example:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames('funcName');
 function funcName()   
 {   
    //...  
 }
```

### jQuery

Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded

```
$(function() {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");`